# Sorting nvarchar column containing alphanumeric values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, natural-sort

One of my columns in a SQL Server 2005 table contains alphanumeric values and I want to sort the rows as per the alphanumeric sorting. `HOUSE_NO` is a `NVARCHAR` column and it contains values like this:

```
 - 2/1 NAWOG
 - 1/1
 - 2/1 A
 - 1/2 A GOLCHA
 - 1
 - 2
 - SHASWAT KUTIR
 - 3 A
 - 11/1
 - 11
```

And I want them to be sorted as:

```
 - 1
 - 1/1
 - 1/2 A GOLCHA
 - 2
 - 2/1 A
 - 2/1  NAWAG
 - 3 A
 - 11
 - 11/1
 - SHASWAT KUTIR
```

I have tried many methods but not successful. I need your suggestions

Comment: @zerkms: `nvarchar` implies Oracle (AFAIK).

Comment: @mu is too short: not actually (`mysql> create table a (b nvarchar(1)); 
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)`) But seems like you guessed right ;-)

Comment: And I guess 2/2 also would have to come before 2/11. Makes me wonder how the 'natural' sort order is for '3 A', '3/1' and '3A'. Would be a fun excercise to stuff all that into a query but it would be a horrendous one with probably dramatic performance. You should normalize this numbering scheme somehow into multiple columns or add columns specifically for creating sorting values

Answer (score 1):

Yuck. This is not something you're going to want to do in T-SQL against large data sets.

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(HOUSE_NO NVARCHAR(32));

INSERT @x SELECT '2/1 NAWOG'
UNION ALL SELECT '1/1'
UNION ALL SELECT '2/1 A'
UNION ALL SELECT '1/2 A GOLCHA'
UNION ALL SELECT '1'
UNION ALL SELECT '2'
UNION ALL SELECT 'SHASWAT KUTIR'
UNION ALL SELECT '3 A'
UNION ALL SELECT '11/1'
UNION ALL SELECT '11';

DECLARE @n NVARCHAR(10) = N'%[^0-9]%'

SELECT HOUSE_NO FROM @x
    ORDER BY CASE 
        WHEN HOUSE_NO LIKE N'[0-9]' + @n
        THEN CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(HOUSE_NO, 1, PATINDEX(@n, HOUSE_NO)-1))
        WHEN HOUSE_NO NOT LIKE @n THEN CONVERT(INT, HOUSE_NO)
        ELSE 2147483647 END,
        CASE WHEN HOUSE_NO NOT LIKE @n THEN NULL
        ELSE SUBSTRING(HOUSE_NO, PATINDEX(@n, HOUSE_NO), LEN(HOUSE_NO)) END;
```

What is the point of sorting house numbers in the way anyway?

Comment: Sadly enough this only partially does the job. It takes the first section and converts everything to its number part. the sorts on the rest. This ignores the fact that after the number there can be more number parts like '1/11' vs '1/2'. Still your answer does point in the right direction how this (theoretically it can be solved by adding more of this constructs) and +1 for the YUCK

Comment: @Eddy, I've sorted exactly how the op requested. Can you edit the question to include some values to demonstrate where my solution breaks down, and confirm that values of that form are actually possible in the user's system?

Comment: What I'm getting at is that we can only solve the problem that has been presented. We could also jump to the conclusion that there are values like 'shaswat kutir/12' and that he'd want that to sort before the string without the slash. I'm not going to break my back coding additional assumptions that would only mean a question was sadly incomplete.